# Strange address conversion in C/C++?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-address

I can't say that I know C/C++ bad, but I've encountered with interesting syntax.
I have this code:

```
int i=7;
char* m=(char*)&i;
m[2]=9;
cout<<i;
```

Its output 589831. So can someone explain me in details what is going here.

Comment: `589831` is `090007` in hexa

Comment: You can verify this if you have Win7.  Start the calculator, switch it to programmers view.  In Dec (decimal) mode type in 589831.  Then switch to bin or hex.

Comment: In technical terms, this is known as "crappy code".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The integer `i` very likely takes 4 bytes, arranged with the lowest value first (little endian). In memory the values look like this:

```
0x07 0x00 0x00 0x00
```

You changed the value at index 2 so now it looks like:

```
0x07 0x00 0x09 0x00
```

If you reverse the bytes and put them back together, they make the hex value 0x00090007 which is the same as 589831 in decimal.

Answer (score 3):

1. a 4-byte integer is filled with the number 7.
2. the 4-byte integer is mapped to an array of four single bytes (chars). On a little-endian architecture like x86 the least significant bytes come first in a number, so the array looks like this in memory: `{ 07, 00, 00, 00 }`
3. the 3rd byte of the integer slash byte array is changed to 9. It now looks like this: `{ 07, 00, 09, 00 }`
4. the resulting integer (hexadecimal 90007) is written to stdout (in decimal format: 589831).

Long story short, it's an example how you can manipulate individual bytes in a multi-byte integer.

Answer (score 1):

You are casting the integer address to a `char*` then modifying it using array notation. This step

```
m[2] = 9;
```

is the same as the pointer arithmetic

```
*(m+2) = 9;
```

that is to say, it is modifying the byte at address of `m` + 2 bytes. Thus you have changed one of the bytes (3rd) in your initial integer value

Answer (score 1):

Here is my breakdown of what is going on, then an explanation.

```
// An integer on the stack, probably 4 bytes big, but we can't say that for sure.
int i=7; // Looks like 0x0000007 in memory. Endianness needs to be considered.

// Treat that integer as a \0 terminated string.
char* m=(char*)&i; // Acts as an empty string since the first byte is a 0, but we can't count on that.

// Set the second byte to 9.
m[2]=9; // Results in i being 0x00090007 (589831 decimal) on whatever architecture you are running. Once again, can't count on it.

// Print the modified integer.
cout<<i;
```

This is an incredibly dangerous and stupid thing to do for three reasons...

1. You should not count on the [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) of your architecture. Your code may end up running on a CPU that has a different underlying representation of what an `int` is.
2. You cannot count on `int` to always be 4 bytes.
3. You now have a `char*` that if you ever go to perform a string operation on it could cause a crash. In your specific case, it will print an empty string, but it would not take much for that integer to not have a 0 byte in it and go on reading other parts of your stack.

If you *really, really, really* need to do this, the preferred method is to use [unions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_%28computer_science%29#C.2FC.2B.2B) but this kind of bit twiddling is very error prone and unions do very little to help.

Comment: “// Treat that integer as a \0 terminated string.” `char*` means, literally, pointer to `char`. A pointer to char may be used to point to a \0-terminated string but it is not a fault of the code being discussed, whatever its qualities, to use a `char *` to point to something other than a \0-terminated string. No-one ever said that was the only thing a `char *` could point to.

Comment: I suppose you are correct. I guess when I see a `char*` my brain heads straight to: *this is a string*. In this case, it is being treated as a char array with no terminator.

Answer (score 0):

`int i=7` reserves 4 bytes of memory for integer and depending on CPU architecture (lets say yours is i86) would produce something like this in memory
`7 0 0 0`

then a pointer m created to point at the beginning of `7 0 0 0` .
after `m[2] = 9` memory should look like 
`7 0 9 0` (arrays are zero based);

then you printout i